# JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE On linux mint

Tags: java, linux, maven, linux-mint

If anyone can help it would mean a lot, as there are many similarly answered questions but mostly for windows, I am running Linux mint 20.2 (Uma).

As the title states I cannot launch maven without the error popping up, I've set the jdk and maven path, but it just doesn't seem to work, echoing the path gives me this output

```
brainlet@brainlet-HP-ProBook-450-G6:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java/jdk-16.0.2
brainlet@brainlet-HP-ProBook-450-G6:~$ echo $M2_HOME
/opt/apache-maven
brainlet@brainlet-HP-ProBook-450-G6:~$ echo $M2
/opt/apache-maven/bin
brainlet@brainlet-HP-ProBook-450-G6:~$
```

And trying to run maven at all, I get this output

```
brainlet@brainlet-HP-ProBook-450-G6:~$ mvn
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

I cannot figure out why it keeps bringing up the error, nor can I find a specific solution for my problem.
Any input is much appreciated, and thank you all in advance.

Comment: What's the output of `ls "$JAVA_HOME/bin/javac"` in the same terminal where you ran `mvn`?

Comment: Here is the output  ```brainlet@brainlet-HP-ProBook-450-G6:~$ mvn
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
brainlet@brainlet-HP-ProBook-450-G6:~$ ls "$JAVA_HOME/bin/javac"
/usr/java/jdk-16.0.2/bin/javac```

Comment: Does `env | grep JAVA_HOME` output anything?

Comment: Yes it does                                                                                                                       
 ```brainlet@brainlet-HP-ProBook-450-G6:~$ env | grep JAVA_HOME
       JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk-16.0.2```

Comment: A simple test like `sh -c 'echo "$JAVA_HOME"'` would be sufficient. If you're seeing a blank line, you didn't ***export*** that variable.

Comment: Nope it gives an output ```$ sh -c 'echo "$JAVA_HOME"'
/usr/java/jdk-16.0.2```

Comment: Weird. Does `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java` exist as well, just like `javac`?

Comment: Yes it does ```brainlet@brainlet-HP-ProBook-450-G6:~$ ls "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
/usr/java/jdk-16.0.2/bin/java```

Comment: The logic giving the message is [here](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/35e05e497234a353219d7a3d1ce374a91671e928/apache-maven/src/assembly/shared/init#L53). The variable appears to be exported and the files are there, so unless you ran the commands in different terminals, `"$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"` is weirdly not executable, or you have some alias/wrapper for `mvn`, then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: yes, i ran the commands in the same terminal, and re-ran them just to make sure. Tho I think it might have to do with that, and or i messed up something way back when i was setting up maven on this system, tho it's been so long since i used this laptop i don't know where to begin or what i messed up\ where do i even start looking.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l "$(which java)"`?

Comment: It's brainlet@brainlet-HP-ProBook-450-G6:~$ ls -l "$(which java)"
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Aug  2  2021 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java

Comment: Aha! Your $JAVA_HOME is not correctly set or at least your jdk was not properly installed. I'm pretty sure you'll get a warning if you `unset JAVA_HOME` then run mvn.

Comment: I tried and got the same error ```brainlet@brainlet-HP-ProBook-450-G6:~$ unset JAVA_HOME
brainlet@brainlet-HP-ProBook-450-G6:~$ mvn
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE```

Comment: I'm out of ideas.  `type -a java` would probably help and `chmod +x <path>/java` em all. I'd suggest to run this first and see if the error still persist. `chmod +x "$JAVA_HOME"/bin/java`. If it does helps, don't forget to `chmod`ing other binaries as well.

Comment: I have gotten to the point where i'm trying to uninstall java from my system completely but after following multiple guides ```java --version``` still has an output, if you guys by any chance know what's going on the help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I uninstalled maven and the old jdk however, putting in the command ```env | grep JAVA_HOME``` Gives me the output ```JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.2
PATH=/opt/apache-maven/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/java/jdk-16.0.2/bin:/opt/lampp/bin/:/opt/maven/bin:/snap/bin:JAVA_HOME/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.2/jre/bin```
The old and maven path i set is still there even though my ```/etc/environment``` has this in it ```PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/lampp/bin/"```

Comment: I also found a ```maven.sh``` file in the ```/etc/profile.d/``` directory, that was setting the old JDK path and m2 path, i deleted it, but I still think something is redirecting maven in my IDE to the old JDK path and or it's not set properly.  Though I don't know where to look, if you guys are still in this thread any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well 3x. Post your `env | sort` in the question. Run these: `which java`, `java --version`, `type -a java`. Your $PATH seems incorrect. It shouldn't print `JAVA_HOME/bin`. If you edited that file yourself, then you forgot to put a `$` -- `$JAVA_HOME/bin`. When you run `env | grep JAVA_HOME`, you should only see a line that prints `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.2`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that by specifying the correct JDK path in `~/.mavenrc` file.

```
$ cat ~/.mavenrc 
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.13.0-openjdk-amd64
```